# access view inside a storyboard

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

How does one access, in code, a view they dragged from the Object Browser into another view in their storyboard?

For example, I created a UIView which I assigned to a ViewController class.  Then I dragged a Map View into that view.  Now I need to start manipulating that Map View in code.  How do I access it?  I've tried things like self.view.subview but haven't gotten anywhere from there.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use outlets, first select your storyboard file, then go to

```
View->Assistant Editor->Show Assistant Editor
```

[image]

Next select the map view, press `control` on your keyboard and drag to the right section of xcode that will show your .h file, the following will appear

[image]

Write mapView inside it and hit enter, this will create an outlet for you to use
Now you can use mapView to access your MKMapView

Comment: Please, at least *mention* IBOutlets. viewWithTag is so much more fragile ad opaque.

Comment: @BJHomer yes you are completly right, i just changed my answer :)

Comment: @BJHomer could you explain a bit more about why viewWithTag is fragile and opaque?  Or maybe point me to somewhere else that explains it?