# Reading sub elements coordinates in superview/parent view controller in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, parent-child, subview

So I've created a view controller that creates a custom view that, if it holds two elements, creates a line between them. A separator.

The view and its elements are created in Interface Builder and their placement set there.

What I am trying to do is to read the sub elements origin coordinates and width/height so that I can dynamically draw the separator between them.

I've tried using the `NSArray self.subviews` and tried using the methods `convertRect` and `convertPoint` which are found in the `NSView` class.

Does anyone know how I might do this?

All help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a fairly interesting request, but I think this should work fairly well.  This assumes the subviews are left/right, if you need up/down, then reverse the >= to <= and compare y instead of x.

```
-(void)example {
        if (self.view.subviews.count ==2) {
             CGPoint origin1 = [self.view.subviews objectAtIndex:0].frame.origin;
             CGPoint origin2 = [self.view.subviews objectAtIndex1].frame.origin;
             if (origin1.x >= origin2.x)
                 [[self.view.subviews objectAtIndex:0]setFrame:someFrameOnTheLeft];
                 [[self.view.subviews objectAtIndex:0]setFrame:someFrameOnTheRight];
              }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Link an outlet to each subview from the xib see this [access view inside a storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11276738/access-view-inside-a-storyboard/11276770#11276770)

Call your outlets `upperView`, and `lowerView`

Now to get the origin of the view use

```
float x = upperView.frame.origin.x;
float y = upperView.frame.origin.y;
```

Comment: Yes that would work, but what I am doing is trying to create a dynamic view controller that can detect if certain elements are present and from their information do certain ui tuning. Thx for trying to help though.