# Ios - syntax error trying to add a listener to the textview

Tags: ios, ios5

I have a textView for which the submit button gets overlapped by the keyboard, so I am trying to add a listener for when a user taps anywhere else on the screen to get rid of the keyboard.

I am trying to add code like this to my controller:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *) touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [textView resignFirstResponder];
}
```

but this gives a syntax error that the textView is not declared.  But that is confusing because I added the textView to the screen already.

Here is the code:

```
#import "FeedbackController.h"

@interface FeedbackController ()

@end

@implementation FeedbackController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}



- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *) touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [textView resignFirstResponder];
}

- (IBAction)submitFeedback:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"This is a test hello");
}
@end
```

And here is how the screen looks like: 
[image]

Any idea how I can try to reference the textView correctly? and how I can make the keyboard disappear when the other parts of the screen are touched?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to just fix your user interface so that it doesn't overlap, I'd say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your .h file you will need to create an `IBOutlet` to the `textView` variable, here is how you create the outlet [access view inside a storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11276738/access-view-inside-a-storyboard)

Comment: Thanks, I was able to crate this line in the header file: @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *textArea;

Comment: textArea is the name I gave it.  But how do I reference it now in the .m file?

Comment: Should it be [self.textArea resignFirstRespnder]

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a property for your textView which is an IBOutlet. Then you can connect it in interface builder and call:

```
[self.textView resignFirstRespnder]
```

when you want the keyboard to hide.